# Changing R.java file content

Tags: java, android

Is there any possibility to change or hide the content that is listed inside?

```
     public static final int pref_help_resumability_message=0x7f0b003f;
     public static final int pref_help_resumability_summary=0x7f0b0040;
     public static final int pref_help_resumability_title=0x7f0b0041;
```

[Source code wished to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW6zj.png)

[content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m81M.png)

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Don't link to external content - instead include a minimal but reasonable example into your question.

Comment: what you want to change there ?.. and why ? This is system auto generated file.

Comment: @GhostCat will do. tq.

Comment: @SRBbans Hello, i would like to hide the setting function..but it is linked to the R.file. everytime i try to remove any block of the content, it crashes. You can see the content from the picture(content) above. TQ

Comment: @student.r R.java file is auto generated file where all resources(in your project) Id's are stored. when you run ur app system try to find the ids in R.java file. If it not found there, if will give you the exception resource not found something.

Comment: @SRBbans oh i see. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @student.r If it is really helpful, accepting the answer is the best way to say thanks on SOF. :) mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Changing R.java file content

R.java is not just where XML ids are stored. It also contains access to resources - such as drawables, layouts, strings, arrays, and basically anything you can declare in resources.

R.java file is an auto-generated file by aapt (Android Asset Packaging Tool) that contains resource IDs for all the resources of res/ directory. when you create any component in the xml file, id for the corresponding component is automatically created in this file. This id can be used in the activity source file to perform any action on the component.

**So,**

If you want to hide something you have to find the view using `findViewById(R.id.yourViewId);` and then set the vissiblity to `Gone` or `Invisible`. or you can simply hide it from xml using vissiblity attributes.

Comment: Nice comprehensive answer!